# enum and valuetype

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why enums require an explicit cast to int type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728295/why-enums-require-an-explicit-cast-to-int-type)

I defined this enumeration:

```
public enum GroupTypes : int
{
    gt_table0 = 0
    gt_table1 = gt_table0 + 1,
    gt_table2 = gt_table1 + 1,
    gt_table3 = gt_table2 + 1,
    gt_table4 = gt_table3 + 1,
    gt_table5 = gt_table4 + 1,
    gt_table6 = gt_table5 + 1,
    gt_table7 = gt_table6 + 1,
    gt_table8 = gt_table7 + 1
}
```

I then use this enum as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NbrTables; i++)
{
    // Compute starting table
    int StartGroup = GroupTypes.gt_table0 + i;

    // Some more code here        
}
```

Where I am confused is when I use the enumeration to compute my StartGroup, I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'GroupTypes' to 'int'.  An explicit conversion exists'.

I thought that I would avoid this error since I declared the GroupTypes enum as an int.

Where is my mis-understanding?

Answer (score 6):

> I thought that I would avoid this error since I declared the
>   GroupTypes enum as an int.

Since your enum is an int, you can do this *if you specify the cast explicitly*:

```
int StartGroup = (int)GroupTypes.gt_table0 + i;
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of : int only affects the storage class of the enum, but not any of its behaviour

Comment: Thank you!  Today, I learned.