# Passing enum member to method

Tags: c#

How can I call a method that expects an int value by using an enum member.  I dont want the called method to have to know about the enum.

```
public enum Volume : int
{
    Low = 1,
    Medium = 2,
    High = 3
}

public void Start() {
    DoSomeWork(Volume.Low);  //this complains
    //this works  DoSomething((int)Volume.Low);

}

public void DoSomeWork(int vol) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: You have the answer in the question yourself.  Why even ask the question?  Having said that, you'd be much better off having the method accept the enum.  Having it accept a magic int is going to make that method very confusing for callers who need to memorize what int means what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it explicitly to `int` (as you have already figured out):

```
DoSomeWork((int)Volume.Low)
```

Implicit conversion from enum to underlying type is forbidden, since there are a lot of cases when this conversion does not make sense. @EricLippert explains this well enough [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728359/728795).

However why introduce the enum if you are not using it? If the volume rate in your program is specified by the enum - then this is the type your method should expect as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, but id rather not.  Shouldnt the compiler know that Volume.Low is of type int, especially since I set the base type of the enum?

Comment: @bitshift, please see the update with some explanation

Comment: Well, now that I looked it up, both the enum member and an int might be the same intregal type, they need an explicit cast to go from one to the other.  http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson17

Answer (score 1):

Call it like this:

```
DoSomeWork( (int) Volume.Low );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this way:

```
public void DoSomeWork(Volume volume) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as documentation states

`Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char.       The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int.`

so you can just simple cast it to int and pass it to the method that way.

```
DoSomeWork((int)Volume.Low);
```