# How to use enum values?

Tags: c#

I have the following `enum`:

```
enum Crank { X = 0, Y = 1 }
```

However when I try

```
if (x == Crank.X)
```

I get an error indicating

```
cannot convert from Crank to int
```

Where do i go wrong?

Comment: Assuming `x` is an int, you can cast the enum value to an int to compare them, i.e. `if (x == (int)Crank.X)`

Comment: thanks. however why do I need to cast it?? I gave it value 0...

Comment: From docs: The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. However, an explicit cast is necessary to convert from enum type to an integral type.

Comment: thanks both for the help!!

Comment: See [Why enums require an explicit cast to int type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728295/why-enums-require-an-explicit-cast-to-int-type) for a great explanation of why this is required.

Comment: I am mistaken here:) @stuartd

Comment: @stuartd even though sure, it makes sense, but you can do `enum Crank : int { //values }` and it still won't let you. That is poor implementation, you should be able to compare ints if you define it to only take ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If x is of type integer, you need to cast the enum value to an int to compare
`if(x==(int)Crank.X)`